# How to make a simple division of Double by Int in Swift?

Tags: swift

Looking at various posts on this topic but still no luck. Is there a simple way to make division/conversion when dividing Double (or Float) with Int? Here is a simple example in playground returning and error "Double is not convertible to UInt8".

```
    var score:Double = 3.00
var length:Int = 2  // it is taken from some an array lenght and does not return decimal or float

var result:Double = (score / length )
```

Answer (score 14):

Cast the int to double with `var result:Double=(score/Double(length))`
What this will do is before computing the division it will create a new Double variable with int inside parentheses hence constructor like syntax.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot combine or use different variable types together.
You need to convert them all to the same type, to be able to divide them together. 
The easiest way I see to make that happen, would be to make the Int a Double. 
You can do that quite simply do that by adding a ".0" on the end of the Integer you want to convert.

Also, FYI:
Floats are pretty rarely used, so unless you're using them for something specific, its also just more fluid to use more common variables.

---